# How to filter const types and non const types using meta programing?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, type-deduction

I have this code

```
#include <iostream>

size_t F()
{
        return 0;
}

template <class Type, class... NextTypes>
size_t F(const Type& type, const NextTypes&... nextTypes)
{
        if (!std::is_const<Type>::value)
                return sizeof(type) + F(nextTypes...);
        else
                return F(nextTypes...);
}

int main()
{
  int a = 0;
  const int b = 0;
  const size_t size = F(a,b);
  std::cout << "size = " << size << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to know in compilation time the total size of constant parameters and non const parameters. The current out put is 8, for some reason the compiler thinks `b` is not constant, I used `typeid` and `decltype` to print the types of `a` and `b` and indeed the output shows `b` is an `int` and not `const  int` as I expected. What am I missing? Is it possible to separate a variadic set of arguments to const arguments and non const?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this function template:

```
template<typename T>
void deduce(const T&);
```

If you let the compiler deduce a type for `T` from an argument expression, the deduced type will never be `const`: It will try to make the `const T` of the function parameter identical to the type of the argument expression used to call the function. For example:

```
struct cls {};
const cls c;

deduce(c) // deduces T == cls
```

By deducing `T == cls`, the compiler succeeds in making `const T` identical to the argument type `const cls`. There is no reason for the compiler to produce two different functions for const- and non-const argument types; the parameter type of the function template instantiation will be const-qualified in any case: you requested it by saying `const T&` instead of, say, `T&`.

---

You can deduce the const-ness of an argument by *not* cv-qualifying the function parameter:

```
template<typename T>
void deduce(T&);
```

However, this will fail to bind to non-const temporaries (rvalues). To support them as well, you can use *universal references*:

```
template<typename T>
void deduce(T&&);
```

This will deduce an lvalue-reference type for `T` if the argument is an lvalue, and no reference if the argument is an rvalue. The const-ness will be deduced correctly.

For example, if the argument has the type `const A` and is an lvalue, `T` will be deduced to `const A&`. The function parameter then is `const A& &&`, which is collapsed to `const A&` (an lvalue-reference). If the argument is an rvalue, `T` will be deduced to `const A`, and the function parameter becomes `const A&&` (an rvalue-reference).

Note that since `T` can be a reference in this case, you need to remove that before checking for const-ness: `std::is_const< typename std::remove_reference<T>::type >::value`.

Comment: *"There is no reason for the compiler to produce two different functions for const- and non-const argument types"* This is just a guess. I don't know the actual rationale.